# Iterate over select DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jQuery, I'd like to iterate only over certain elements. Right now I have this double loop which loops over all DOM elements and each of their attributes:

```
  domElement.find('*').each(function () {  //loop over all child elements inside parent

                $.each(this.attributes, function (i, attrib) {
                    var name = attrib.name;
                    var value = attrib.value;

                });
            });
```

my question is - instead of looping over all elements (*) can I somehow select a set of tags to loop over, for example only span,input,button, form, etc?

The more verbose way would be something like this:

```
      domElement.find('*').each(function () {  //loop over all child elements inside parent

               if(this.tagname is in ['span','input','button','form']){  //pseudocode

                    $.each(this.attributes, function (i, attrib) {
                        var name = attrib.name;
                        var value = attrib.value;


                    });
                 }
            });
```

Comment: Did you try replacing `*` with `span, input, button, form`

Comment: Sure. `.find('span,input,button,form')` would work.

Comment: this is difficult to google guys, so that's why I asked

Comment: “what does jQuery’s find do” https://api.jquery.com/find

Comment: hey minitech thanks, if you can find one example online that actually shows multiple tags in the find then please post here, the link you provided does not

Comment: Learn what a CSS selector is. It’s kind of vital to web development.

Comment: An example selector that shows multiple tags:  https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/  this was linked from the /find link provided ".find(selector)" "type:selector" then "selectors api page" and about 2/3rds down of that page: Multiple Selector.

Comment: Alright, to avoid coming down too hard with the RTFM stick, it probably would be beneficial to read some more introductory material on jQuery. A very large majority of jQuery's API allows you to pass in selector strings, and as @minitech pointed out, they're pretty vital to web development in general. This is probably a useful article on selectors in particular: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Comment: I am in the process of learning what a CSS selector is, and thanks for helping out. Not every developer is a web developer.

Comment: Ouch! That's an expensive operation double looping everything in the dom

Comment: yep, I know :) that's why I only want to do the nested loop on elements that matter. Although, there really aren't that many elements inside the parent element in the outside loop nor are there that many attributes per tag.

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple selectors: [JQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

I think in your example the code would be this:

```
var selectList = $('span, input, button, form');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('span,input,button,form').each(function (i, attrib) {
    var name = attrib.name;
    var value = attrib.value;
});
```

Though Mouhamed Halloul's suggestion is better, give them a common class then loop over that class:

```
$('.common-class-name').each(function (i, attrib) {
    var name = attrib.name;
    var value = attrib.value;
});
```